# Django Urlpatter for String

Tags: python, django

I looked up in the net, but cannot find any answer (maybe my search term is not accurate)

I want to pass a string parameter in the django url, by using this pattern:

```
 urlpatterns=('item.views',
    url(r'^receive/find/(?P<key>\s+)/$', 'find'))
```

For example the passed url will be something line this `/item/receive/PO/`. But django never recognizes this as the pattern above.

Please take not that the url is decoupled into `item` app `urls`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pattern, `\s` matches a whitespace character. Try with `\w`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Examples

Comment: In your example, the correct URL (after making the correction in this answer), is `/item/receive/find/PO/` not `/item/receive/PO/`